# SQL Request Intersect and EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle, exists, intersect

I would like to know if the following request can be written with INTERSECT and EXIST keywords. My teacher asked me to solve a problem but I managed to do it only this way.

The technology used is Oracle.

The tables:

```
COMPUTER(id, name, ip, type, room, softwares)
INSTALLATION (id_computer, id_software, installation_date)
SOFTWARE(id, name, purschase_date, version, type, installations)
```

Some rows:

```
c1, computer 1, 192.168.1.1 UNIX, 3, 5 (COMPUTER TABLE)
c1, s1, 21/11/16 (INSTALLATION TABLE)
s1, Notepad++, 05/04/98, 2.0, UNIX, 3 (SOFTWARE TABLE)
```

The question is to get the computers names which have at least one same software installed with the computer 6 "c6" by using INTERSECT and EXISTS.

So far, this is working but doesn't answer the question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_computer
FROM INSTALLATION
WHERE id_software IN (
    SELECT id_software
    FROM INSTALLATION
    WHERE id_computer = 'c6'
) AND id_computer <> 'c6';
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

### TRY THIS

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_computer
FROM INSTALLATION bb
WHERE exists (
    SELECT 1
    FROM INSTALLATION aa
    WHERE aa.id_computer = 'c6'
   and aa.id_software=bb.id_software
) AND id_computer <> 'c6';
```